# Query repeated fields negation NOT include

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query a string repeated field using NOT contain (regex)

This is the query, where nickname is an array (repeated) of strings:

```
 SELECT
    name
  FROM
    [mytable]
  WHERE
     (NOT  REGEXP_MATCH (nickname, '(query)'))
```

The problem is when users have at least two values under nickname, they will be returned if I query using NOT

For:
NOT  REGEXP_MATCH (nickname, '(jonny)')

```
name     nickname 

john    [johhny,jonny]
jon     [jonny]
```

will return john and it shouldn't be.

Comment: You have the wrong data model.  You can store the values in an array or in a separate table with one row per nickname.  Don't try to make this work.  Fix the data model.

Comment: Can't fix the data model. This is how bigquery keeps the data. It's not mysql.

Comment: . . BigQuery offers arrays and `JOIN`, either of which are more appropriate for this type of data.  You *don't* have to do string munging to store a list.

Comment: yes, that's an array or nicknames. Mysql has a series of rules which don't apply to bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to express this kind of logic using `NOT EXISTS` or an `ARRAY` subquery with [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/). For example,

```
#standardSQL
WITH Names AS (
  SELECT 'john' AS name, ['johnny', 'jonny'] AS nicknames UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jon' AS name, ['jonny'] AS nicknames
)
SELECT
  name
FROM Names
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(nicknames) AS nickname
  WHERE nickname LIKE '%johnny%'
);
```

As another example, you may want to include just the nicknames not matching the substring:

```
#standardSQL
WITH Names AS (
  SELECT 'john' AS name, ['johnny', 'jonny'] AS nicknames UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jon' AS name, ['jonny'] AS nicknames
)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    name,
    ARRAY(SELECT nickname FROM UNNEST(nicknames) AS nickname
          WHERE nickname NOT LIKE '%johnny%') AS nicknames
  FROM Names
)
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(nicknames) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are still bound to BigQuery Legacy SQL, below is respective solution

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT name FROM (
  SELECT
    name, SUM(nicknames LIKE '%johnny%') WITHIN RECORD AS matches
  FROM [mytable]
)
WHERE matches = 0
```

Comment: yes, I'm bound to legacy for now. I'll try this as well. Meanwhile I found a similar solution using an extra select with group by and group_concat.

Comment: @AlexandruRada - if it is using extra select with grouping and group_concat - it is sure not similar :o) meantime, have you tried above solution? did it help?